# AWS lambda R runtime segmentation fault

Tags: r, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I am attempting to create a runtime layer to enable using R as the runtime for lambda functions using their [new runtime API](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-for-aws-lambda-use-any-programming-language-and-share-common-components/).

To do this, I have created a layer that contains all the dependencies needed for R, and then a second layer containing R itself.  I built these  layers using the same Amazon AMI that lambda runs on.  I tested my build by zipping up my layers, creating a fresh instance, and then downloading and unzipping the layers into that new instance (putting everything in /opt, which also happens to be where I installed R and its dependencies when I built them).  I used an instance type with minimal resources (2 cpu, 4GB  RAM). As I understand it, this should then very closely approximate the lambda environment.

I have a little test script (test.r) that simply prints a message to stdout. 
This runs fine in the test environment.  Here is the script:

```
cat("hello from planet lambdar")
```

And here is how it is invoked in the bootstrap script in my layer:

```
SCRIPT=$LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT/$(echo "$_HANDLER" | cut -d. -f1).r
  echo "About to run $SCRIPT"
  /opt/R/bin/Rscript $SCRIPT
```

From the logging below, it is apparent that the name of the script gets sent and parsed correctly.  I have previously confirmed that the script test.r lands in /var/task as expected.  But running this script via lambda results in a segmentation fault:

```
START RequestId: 2c1b8801-f903-11e8-a32d-796c039278f1 Version: $LATEST
About to run /var/task/test.r
/opt/bootstrap: line 18:    18 Segmentation fault      (core dumped) /opt/R/bin/Rscript $SCRIPT
```

How do I debug this segmentation fault given that the process runs fine on a minimal EC2 instance running the same Amazon AMI used by lambda, loaded with the same set of tools and dependencies I created for the the layers I added to my lambda function?

Comment: I am facing the exact same issue. Looks like it's an issue with AWS itself. Error returned from our logs: `signal: SIGSEGV, stdout: , stderr:`

Comment: @KauêGimenes see my answer below.  Hopefully a few tidbits in their that will be helpful to your situation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In this case, it turned out that I was overly aggressive in copying shared libraries linked to the R executable into my layer.  I took everything listed by

```
ldd /opt/R/lib/libR.so
```

and copied it to /opt/lib

The problem is that many of those libraries were already in the AMI, and their presence in a different location caused problems (perhaps related to the library cache?).

By moving only the two libraries that were not in the AMI (but added when I installed the build tools, which of course are not in the Lambda environment), the segfault went away.  These two libraries are:

```
/usr/lib64/libgfortran.so.3
/usr/lib64/libquadmath.so.0
```

**To answer the deeper question** here, namely how to debug segfaults in the Lambda environment, I found inspiration [here](https://www.commandlinefu.com/commands/view/6004/print-stack-trace-of-a-core-file-without-needing-to-enter-gdb-interactively), and included something like this in my `bootstrap` script to print the backtrace from the core dump:

```
gdb -q -n -ex bt -batch /opt/R/bin/Rscript /temp/core.N.XXXX
```

Where core.N.XXXX was the name of the core dump file (which can be discovered by putting `echo $(ls /tmp)` in your `bootstrap` script).  The cloudwatch logs will then contain at least some hints from the backtrace.

Comment: I don't suppose you've documented how you made a custom R runtime? I'd love to try it but am not really sure how to get started.

Comment: @user2380153 You are in luck: https://github.com/VanAndelInstitute/lambdaR. Feel free to open issues there if you run into any problems.

Comment: @user2380153 We published our runtime as well https://github.com/bakdata/aws-lambda-r-runtime

Comment: Thank you both! I was running into issues getting the deployment package under 50MB, I'm glad to see you ran into the same issue and worked around it.